# MXE and QT deployment gives Runtime Error

Tags: c++, qt, mxe

I'm building a **QT** application on Ubuntu that works pretty good. Now I have to deploy it on Windows, so I installed **MXE** in order to cross compile my sources.

## MXE build

```
git clone https://github.com/mxe/mxe.git
cd mxe
# I need posix threads, that why I build static.posix target
make MXE_TARGETS='i686-w64-mingw32.static.posix' qtbase libxml2
```

I use a personal library (that uses `cmake`) and a client/server code for my **QT** code, that I compiled with **MXE** and it did not give any error (I worked hard to fix them...). Then, the compilation for the **QT** reaches the end without any error.

Whenever I try to execute the program (with `wine` on Ubuntu or on Windows) it does not work. `wine` freezes and Windows shows me a `Runtime Error`.

I also tried to use the `windeployqt.exe` using `wine` on my executable, hopping it will give me the missing dlls, but it tells me :

```
Z:\path\release\Executable.exe 32 bit, release executable
Z:\path\release\Executable.exe does not seem to be a Qt executable.
```

I really have no idea on what is broken. Am I forgetting to put dlls, or is my compilation failing silently ? Does anyone knows or have ideas on how to deal with that case ?

## EDIT

Apparently I compile correctly my program, the error seems to come from `GetAdapterAdresse` when using Windows. The problem is not coming from MXE at all (I'm glad I made it work though).

I'll have to have a look on this function, but anyone knows how to make `gdb` work with **MXE** ? When I ran `make gdb`, it has built something, but I can't figure out where is the program.

Comment: What's the Windows OS version you are trying to run?

Comment: It's Windows 10

Comment: Have you considered using *Dependency Walker* on Windows to see what DLLs are missing? http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: @PhilippLudwig Thanks for your proposition, I'll check that and see what it says !

Comment: @PhilippLudwig Ok so I've been able to list all dlls, but if I copy them (from wine installation) in my executable location, it still does not work neither on Ubuntu nor Windows. Now the new error is "Unable to run the application (0xc000007b)"... I'm going to try each of them until I have something else

Comment: @PhilippLudwig I tried the Profile mode, and I have a bunch of errors, I'm going to compile QT5 with MXE for both 32 and 64 bits and for each of them I'll see...

Comment: Don't forget that for running the application under windows you will also need to provide the necessary Qt plugins; a lot of information is available in the Qt documentation, they also talk about the dependency walker there: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Comment: @PhilippLudwig There might be a problem because I've never seen yet A QT dll listed with Dependency Walker (and QT deployment tool told me before that the executable was not a QT one). It's probably coming from the same error source, but I can't figure out where it comes from (don't forget that I built qt for static compilation). Should I try the shared one?